# Sorting a String ArrayList Alphabetically Error Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am getting these two errors when setting 2 strings equal to one another in a sorting algorithm. Does anyone know why this error is occurring and how to fix it?
Thanks

Picture of the errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xYQD.png

Comment: You cannot swap the values like this.  `List::get` returns a String instead of variable and you cannot assign another string to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a method. Instead, you want to call the `set` method: `ArrayList#set(index, value)`.